# Cannot replace spaCy lemmatized pronouns (-PRON-) through text

Tags: spacy, lemmatization

I'm trying to lemmatise a text with spaCy. Since spaCy uses -PRON- as lemma for personal pronouns, I want to keep the original text in all those cases.

Here's the relevant section of my code:

...

```
fout = open('test.txt', 'w+')
doc = nlp(text)
for word in doc:
    if word.lemma_ == "-PRON-":
        write = word.text
        print(write)
    else:
        write = word.lemma_
    fout.write(str(write))
    fout.write(" ")
```

...

The print statement does print the original words for the cases where spaCy attributes the lemma '-PRON-'.

However, my output file (test.txt) always contains '-PRON-' for those cases, even though I would expect it to write the original words for those cases (I, us etc.)

What am I missing?

I tried different versions, including using the pos_ tag to identify the pronouns etc. but always with the same result, i.e., that my output contains '-PRON-'s

Comment: The above code works for me.  It correctly lemmatizes all words but leaves pronouns untouched.  Are you sure your example fails on your machine?  What version of Spacy?  What version of Python?

Comment: Thank you very much for checking. I have spaCy version 2.2.2, Python version  3.7.4.

Comment: I run it this morning again and it still produces '-PRON-' in the output file, even though it correctly identifies all the instances where it should produce the text instead. No idea what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Try this somewhat altered code snipped to see what you get...

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = 'Did he write the code for her?'
doc = nlp(text)
out_sent = [w.lemma_ if w.lemma_ !='-PRON-' else w.text for w in doc]
out_sent = ' '.join(out_sent)  
print(out_sent)
with open('out_sent.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(out_sent + '\n')
```

This should produce...
`do he write the code for her ?`